# Which one is better : JPA or Hibernate annotation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am confused about these two annotation APIs.
I googled and understand that JPA is interface and Hibernate annotations are implementations.
Is that right?

But which one should I use in my project? Which one is better and why?

Comment: JPA is not an "annotation API". It's an API that allows metadata to be defined for persistable classes (using annotations or XML). I'd suggest you go back to internet searching since there are so many links that explain such basics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will go for JPA as you can easily change the implementation (i.e. JPA vendors) at any time just by changing a single line.Hibernate and other vendors like OpenJPA, Toplink provides implementation to JPA standards.
About annotations, JPA and Hibernate both provides support for `javax.persistence` annotations.

**JPA vs Hibernate**

> a) JPA is Persistence Api which your code should use.
>
> b) JPA Api will pass on the call to actual peristence provider
>   (ex:Hibernate/TopLink) to do the actual work.
>
> c) If you are looking from Performance prespective ,it will be
>   dependent on actual peristence provider (Hibernate/TopLink) and not on
>   JPA as its just a wrapper layer.
>
> d) If you are looking from code dependency prespective ,JPA makes more
>   sense as your code is dependent on standard Java Api.
>
> e) If you have used Hibernate then you will find that certain features
>   are missing in JPA like criteria queries etc.This does not mean that
>   you can’t write criteria query in your application, you need to get
>   Session object from JPA Entity manager and now you are as good as in
>   hibernate project.
>
> But now your code is dependent on Specific impl (Hibernate),going
>   forward you can see more things getting added in JPA (2.0)
>
> f) Should you use JPA: My take is you should ,API is clean and
>   although not everthing you need is their but is a good step forward.

**[Source Link](http://elope.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate/)**

Answer (score 2):

Basically Hibernate implements the JPA spec and also adds more features above th spec. so the Hiberate specific Annotations are those added features. So you use JPA annotations until you come across a mapping that forces you to use Hibernate specific features, then you need to use their annotations to get those features.